# Why does this rvalue reference only work for ints and not structs

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

//option 1
struct Obj
{
    auto f(int&& x) { printf("&&\n"); }
    auto f(int const& x) { printf("const&\n"); }
    
    auto g() const { return int{}; } 
    const auto h() const { return int{}; } 
};

//option 2
struct Obj2
{
    auto f(Obj&& x) { printf("&&\n"); }
    auto f(Obj const& x) { printf("const&\n"); }

    auto g() const { return Obj{}; } 
    const auto h() const { return Obj{}; } 
};

int main()
{
    {
        int x;
        Obj obj;
        obj.f(obj.g()); // prints "&&"
        obj.f(obj.h()); // prints "&&"
    }
    printf("\n");
    {
        Obj x;
        Obj2 obj;
        obj.f(obj.g()); // prints "&&"
        obj.f(obj.h()); // doesn't print "&&" ?! Why?
    }
}
```

As far as I know if you set a value from the return of a function, the return value of the function will be an rvalue.

```
auto x = foo(y); // x always receives an rvalue, right?
```

In the code above, apparently this doesn't always happen. If y is an int it works (option 1) but if y is a struct, return value of g is still an rvalue but not for h. Why? How come it works for ints and not for structs?

**I'm using c++20 and gcc 13.2**

Comment: OT: Please note that returning a constant value is just about useless. Returning a constant *reference* is usable, but not a value that can be copied into a non-constant variable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, ik. I stumbled across this because I accidentally had that const written by accident and it baffled me as to why it should make a difference :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`[expr.type]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-2)

> If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T”, where T is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

In other words, if you return `const T` by value, and `T` is neither a class nor an array, the `const` is silently removed.

When you have a const rvalue, it can't bind to a non-const `T &&`, but can bind to `const T &`, so that overload gets used instead. (A non-const rvalue can bind to both `T &&` and `const T &`, and the former gets priority.)

Thus returning by a const value is almost always a mistake, because it prevents you from moving objects, silently forcing copies. In C++98 it was used to stop people from assigning to rvalues (and move-semantics wasn't a thing), but now you can achieve the same effect by `&`-qualifying the assignment operator.

Comment: wow, you guys are fast. Thanks @HolyBlackCat, "silently forcing copies" That was exactly my problem, it worked for primitive types then for nested templates it was going for op=(const &) and didn't know why :)